# Pass selected option value to axios data post

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have problems during posting a data to database through an API. Right Now i'm using axios to consume API to post the data, by sending all input data from Vue form. It was fine during insertion from input type text but from select option html tag all my selected item was not passed to axios post function. so in database, for the field that supposed to be containing data from selected option input it became empty. But for the field that contain data from input type text, the data exist.  i might made mistake need your help friends. help me to check.

here's the code for the form template :

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Form A</label>
     <select class="select-dropdown-no-search form-control" v-model="statusformA" name="statusformA" id="statusformA">
            <option value="0">Tidak Ada</option>
            <option value="1">Ada</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

here's the Vue and axios code :

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import API from '../API';

var urlAddStock = API.url.host + '/addstock';

var inputMobile = {
    init: function(){
        this.vueConfig();
        API.auth();
    },
    vueConfig: function(){
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                stockSubmit: false,
                statusformA: "",
                access_token: ""
            },
            methods: {
                submitStock: function(){
                    let self = this;
                    this.stockSubmit = true;
                    axios({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: urlAddStock,
                        data: {

                            FormA: this.statusformA,
                            access_token: localStorage.getItem("token")  
                        }
                    }).then(res =>{
                        console.log(res.data);

                        if(res.data.message === "Berhasil Menambahkan Data")
                        {
                            self.stockSubmit = false;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            self.stockSubmit = false;
                        }

                    }, err =>{
                        console.log(err);
                        self.isSubmit = false;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = inputMobile;
```

any of your response will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What triggers your `submitStock()` method?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this at all. The selected value (ie `0` or `1`) is sent as expected ~ https://jsfiddle.net/t6sgcrvz/

Comment: submit button.<div class="col text-right">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="submitStock" v-bind:disabled="stockSubmit" >
                                                            <spinner-loading v-if="stockSubmit"></spinner-loading>
                                                            <span v-if="!stockSubmit">Submit</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>

Comment: @phil maybe i missed a vue tag ini the html form. but i dont know which one

Comment: You don't appear to be preventing the event default for your button click.

Comment: @phil  i put   data: {
                      stockSubmit: false,      after el:#app. but still the same

Comment: I meant, when you click the button (which is a submit button), by default it will submit your form. You can prevent this using `v-on:click.prevent="submitStock"`

Comment: @phil still not working... any other suggestion ? thanks

Comment: @phil, i found solution in my problem above... Vue. JS and axios code above no problem, there's some jquery code that that i need to remove in other file....